# VB6 application requiring comdlg32.ocx, running on windows server 2008

Tags: vb6, ocx, comdlg32

I have a legacy vb6 application that needs to run on a server 2008 machine.
I have been unable to get comdlg32.ocx to register, which the application depends on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the server a 32 bit or 64 bit version of Win2008?

Comment: 64-bit seems likely.  Probably not using a proper installer, but manually copying into System32 instead of SysWOW64.  Hard to say without some basic info though.

Comment: Is there any error message? Are you using regsvr32 or some other method? Are you trying to register it as administrator?

Comment: Thanks for comments, all.  32 bit server.  Used regsvr32 and rebooted yesterday and the app wasn't working. Today the application worked fine, but nothing else was changed.  Wish I could give more information, but the issue seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, does [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx) help you at all?

My only other suggestion is that often [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is useful in these sorts of situations, in particular if you are running this vb6 application on a 64 bit OS then pay attention to whether or not comdlg32.ocx has all of its dependencies present as 32 bit libraries.

Comment: Good link. It says comdlg32.ocx is supported on Windows Server 2008, but you need to distribute it yourself. Therefore mikeh can contact Microsoft technical support if we can't help (I bet it's something simple though).

Comment: "this link" is broken. I've looked in the Web Archive, and found [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20091005065745/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx), which is an accurate snapshot of the linked page at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: @rob or this is a useful link about comdlg32.ocx support http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708

Comment: @MarkJ Thanks for the up-to-date link. I was looking for documentation on this file in order to implement a Open file dialog. I have found [an awesome alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386124/how-can-i-use-the-common-save-as-dialog-from-vbscript/10963270#10963270), which suits my needs: Well-documented, simple to use and no restrictive licenses.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious, but are you running Regsvr32 as an Admin?

Comment: Yes, commented above that the app is working now (but do not know why).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to bother about copying and registering the **comdlg32.ocx** file (for which you might need administrator rights anyway), check out following project, that shows how you can use the common dialog box (open and save) without using the ocx file and thus without need of registering it. It uses the **comdlg32.dll** directly with APIs, which is installed already on windows!
http://www.soft-hummingbird.com/Tutorial_VB_ComdlgAPI.php?lang=en

The **File Backupper** is a nice peace of software, that uses exactly this:
http://www.soft-hummingbird.com/File_Backupper.php?lang=en