# VBS - display multple filetypes in save dialog

Tags: vbscript, savefiledialog

I got the following code to open the save dialog with **one FileType**:

```
Set objDialog = CreateObject("SAFRCFileDlg.FileSave")
objDialog.FileName = "Automatic Generated Presentation"
objDialog.FileType = "PowerPoint 97-2003 Presentation (*.ppt)"
objDialog.OpenFileSaveDlg
```

How can I add another FileType to the combobox / listbox in the dialog?
I tried to seperate them using '|', using ',', using ';' and more - nothing worked ofcourse.

Is that even possible?
I didnt find anything like that in the internet.

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an interesting article where the author debugs Windows API calls made by the `SAFRCFileDlg.FileSave` object to find out whether it allows multiple file filters:
[Debugging the SAFRCDLG.DLL FileType filter string](http://rrudek.wordpress.com/2007/09/12/debugging-the-safrcdlg-dll-filetype-filter-string/)

The answer is **No**.

Comment: Is there another way to call File Save Dialog which allow multiple filters, and not SAFRCFileDlg?

Comment: @Ron: `MSComDlg.CommonDialog` allows multiple file filter (e.g. `objDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"`), but it requires a license. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4464323/113116) for details. Don't know if there're other ActiveX dialog components with this functionality.