# Need to change file name of .csv file to specfic value in sheet

Tags: excel, csv, filenames

Need to change file name of .csv file -which are currently some random site codes with no geo-reference value (e.g. 10001_99998) - to a value = an interesection location (e.g. US 45 @ Main Street) embedded in same row-column pair for several files in the same subfolder.    I would be willing to duplicate / "save as" the existing .csv under the new location-based name also.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: A better way of phasing this would be I am seeking a method in Python to do what this person was seeking to do in .VBS with regard to copying and renaming files so that the filename matched a given cell value:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934817/how-to-save-a-file-with-a-name-which-is-specified-in-a-spreadsheet-using-a-vbs?s=6|0.1700